# Load image into BufferedImage with Apache httpclient

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following code that retreives a page using Apache HttpClient

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(imageUrl));
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println(statusCode);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String entityContents = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

The URL that I'm loading is a direct link to a JPG. How can I load the image directly into a BufferedImage instead of getting the string?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tested code

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/photo.jpg");
request.addHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(entity.getContent());
```